# Is that mandatory to use @XmlRootElement for JSON responce also in Jersey webservices?

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey

My code actually contains one resource class and one BEan class it's return type is JSON.

### Resource Class

```java
@Path("/json")
public class JSONRetrive {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONT getJson(){
        JSONT jsont = new JSONT();
        jsont.setJsont("inr");
        return jsont;
    }
}
```

/* Is there any Annotation will represent JSON. Do i need to use any other Annotation for this.*/

### My Bean class

```java
//@XmlRootElement
public class JSONT {
private String jsont;

public String getJsont() {
    return jsont;
}

public void setJsont(String jsont) {
    this.jsont = jsont;
}

}
```

If i uncomment @XmlRootElement it is working fine is there any other alternative solution for this

Comment: Yes no issue if i use @XmlRootElement and reponse also will be generated, But my Question is with out using JAXB can't we generate response(is there any alternative Annotation or process for JSON Object)

Answer (score 2):

I got alternative solution for this `@XmlRootElement`, if we wanted to generate JSON response with out using `@XmlRootElement` we should go for Jersey Jackson library. Add the below given code in `web.xml` (DD file)

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

and Jackson API related jar's.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jersey and Maven , then just go to your pom.xml and uncomment/add below code depending on your case

```
<!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
-->
```

After this, you can use `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` and you will get JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005668/configure-jersey-jackson-to-not-use-xmlelement-field-annotation-for-json-field) will help? I don't see why is it a problem for you to use the annotation, at least in that case. Can you ellaborate more on the problem this causes to you?