# XmlElement ignored by Jackson during serialization

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson

i'm using Jersey to build a REST service and as Json Processor i set Jackson in my application.

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
   public MyApplication() {
       packages("controller");
       register(JacksonFeature.class);
}
```

I implement a `ContextResolver` for Jacksons `ObjectMapper` (as it's suggested in this post [Configure Jersey/Jackson to NOT use @XmlElement field annotation for JSON field naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005668/configure-jersey-jackson-to-not-use-xmlelement-field-annotation-for-json-field)) which creates an ObjectMapper that doesn't fail on unknown properties during deserialization:

```
@Provider
public class MyJsonObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) 
    {
        System.out.println("mapper!!!");
        ObjectMapper result = new ObjectMapper();
        result.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return result;
    }
}
```

and then i register this class in my application inserting `register(MyJsonObjectMapperProvider.class)` in the class `MyApplication` shown above. I obtain what i want, in sense that if there are unknown properties in the json the object mapper doesn't fail.
My problem is another; i have this class that i use to map a specified Json, in order to deserialize it and subsequently serialize it:

```
public class Version {

    private String status;
    private String updated;
    private String id;
    private List<Link> links;
    @XmlElement(name = "media-types")
    private List<MediaTypes> media_types;

    //constructor + getter and setter
}
```

The problem is about the element *media_types* and the use of the annotation *@XmlElement*. Before i insert the ContextResolver to personalize ObjectMapper all works fine, in fact after serialization i obtain a json in which the element/attribute *media_types* has as name *media-types*; on the contrary with ContextResolver this element doesn't change it's name and has *media_types*. I think that, during serialization, the annotation *XmlElement* doesn't work, but i'm not sure that this is the correct reason.
Another attempt i try to do is to put *@JsonProperty("media-types")* annotation instead of *@XmlElement* annotation but with no result; in fact with this annotation i obtain also a Processing Exception.
The last attempt (in addition to what has been suggested by the previous post) was that of insert these lines of code in the ContextResolver:

```
AnnotationIntrospector intr = new AnnotationIntrospector.Pair(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(),new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
            // usually we use same introspector(s) for both serialization and deserialization:
            result.getDeserializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(intr);
            result.getSerializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(intr);
```

in order to use both JaxbAnnotation and JacksonAnnotation but the name of the field in question remain *media_types*.
I hope i was clear in explain my problem and thanks you in advance for your help!

Comment: If you use field XMLElement annotations, add XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) annotation to the class Version. Don't know if this will help, but with a bit luck ...

Comment: Did any one found an answer for this ? I even asked the same (not this clearly) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878662/how-to-map-fileds-correctly-using-xmlelement-for-dozer