# How to map fields correctly using XmlElement for dozer

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

I have the following field

```
@Mapping("greatId")
@XmlElement(name = "great_key")
private String greatKey;
```

So my getters and setters are `getGreatKey()`, and `setGreatKey(..)`. Then my JSON do not contain the response with field "great_key". But if i add a getter `getGreat_key()`, then it returns the fields. I dont want to add those getters. What am i doing wrong ?

I found exact same problem explained in : [XmlElement ignored by Jackson during serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733907/xmlelement-ignored-by-jackson-during-serialization)

Comment: Is your issue with JSON mapping or dozer bean mapper?

Comment: with the json response. bean mapper works

Comment: Are you using Jackson?

Comment: yes. Sorry for the unclear quesion

Comment: @JamesB i was using FlexJson. Its creating the whole mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure that you are not using Jackson for serialization. ;) Get rid of the current serialization or make it respect the standard annotations.