# Configure Jackson 2.x to NOT use @XmlElement field annotation for JSON field naming

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson

I have looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005668/configure-jersey-jackson-to-not-use-xmlelement-field-annotation-for-json-field) and made it work using

```
.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, true)
.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, true);
```

on my custom `ObjectMapper`

Json serialization works fine with the above configuration.

But the problem is I want to use Jackson 2.x now because of better deserialization control and I cannot find any good documentation indicating how to configure jackson 2.x to ignore JAXB annotations

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I tried `objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false);` but this seems to have no effect on jackson picking up JAXB annotations.

**Second Update**: Posted the solution below as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution which I found was creating my `ObjectMapper` and then registering that with jersey within main method (I am using SpringBoot with jersey as the complete solution).

If I created `ObjectMapper` in other class and tried to register it in main, neither the constructor of that class was being called nor the overridden `getContext()` method. So I created the ObjectMapper within the main method and registered the provider with jersey.

Snippet:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);

// create JsonProvider to provide custom ObjectMapper
JacksonJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJsonProvider();
provider.setMapper(mapper);
```

and

```
register(provider);
```

Maven dependencies, as annotations and JacksonJsonProvider are available in different artifacts:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: On further refactoring realized that problem is mainly in registering a class with '@Provider' annotations with jersey. You can still move this configuration of ObjectMapper to a method of its own or a new class but register it via method call on object and not ClassName.class. (And also you don't need to put '@Provider' annotation on new class)